# How to list all child objects for all parent objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child, ruby-on-rails-6, nested-object

*What I have at the moment is pretty standard set of code, where all child objects can be list under only their parent objects.*

**customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

**booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :customers do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

**bookings_controller.rb**

> This has been automatically generated. I only removed comments and json
>   related lines.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer
  before_action :set_booking, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all.with_attached_images
  end

  def show; end

  def new
    @booking = @customer.bookings.build
  end

  def edit; end

  def create
    @booking = @customer.bookings.build(booking_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.update(booking_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@customer, @booking], notice: 'Booking was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @booking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customer_bookings_url, notice: 'Booking was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  end

  def set_booking
    @booking = @customer.bookings.find(params[:id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:name, :category, :rooms, :wifi, :phone, :address, :description, :available, :check_in, :check_out, :customer_id, images: [])
  end
end
```

I want to list all child objects for all parent objects.

I guess, I will have to modify routes as follows

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'customers#index'

  resources :customers do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :bookings
end
```

I will also need to modify `bookings_controller.rb`

1. By commenting out the line `before_action :set_customer`, otherwise I will get an error like `Couldn't find Customer without an ID`
2. And I will have to put `@customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])` for all methods except `index`. Which means I won't be following DRY concept...

**Any other better approach to solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the best already in my opinion, just need to utilize Rails helpers correctly to keep your code DRY.

> By commenting out the line before_action :set_customer, otherwise I
>   will get an error like Couldn't find Customer without an ID
>
> And I will have to put @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
>   for all methods except index. Which means I won't be following DRY
>   concept...

NO you don't have to.

If the `index` action of `customers/bookings_controller` is not used anywhere else then just remove that action from the controller file and specify the same in the route file as:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :bookings, except: :index
end
```

If the `index` action is still being used in other places then Rails callbacks can be declared with `except` option as below to specify that the `set_customer` will be called for all actions except the `index`.

```
before_action :set_customer, except: :index
```

More about Rails Controller Callback options [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-_normalize_callback_options)

Other points that you may want to check:

1. `dependent: :delete_all`. With this, there will be orphan `active_storage_attachments` records in your db when you delete a `customer`. Because it triggers the callback that deletes only the associated `bookings` when leave the `attached images` of those bookings untouched. [Reference](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all-in-rails-models/)
2. `resources :bookings (last line of your route file)`. If you only have the `index` action in the controller, you should declare the same here also as `resources :bookings, only: :index`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get what you mean by saying `customers/bookings_controller`. I have 2 controllers for customers and bookings.

Comment: I meant the one that is placed in `controllers/customers` folder

Comment: I did following changes:
In `bookings_controller.rb`: `before_action :set_customer, except: :index`
and in `routes.rb` I changed like:
```
  resources :customers do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :bookings, only: :index
```

and when I'm accessing `http://localhost:3000/bookings`
I'm having an error: 
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookings", :customer_id=>nil, :id=>"35"}, missing required keys: [:customer_id]

app/views/bookings/index.html.erb:

<td><%= link_to 'Show', customer_booking_url(@customer, booking)  %></td>

Comment: Are you still experience the bug? why mark my answer so soon :)

Comment: I was able to figure out. Here's my commit https://github.com/tenzan/kaganat/tree/e7b7610132fccd56077aebb67f33075756b84753
If you have time please take a look and please let me know if there's anything missing ;)